# I want to do random sampling from a dataset using Bagging. And use that dataset in further analysis. How can I do that?

Tags: python, random, jupyter-notebook

At first I want to do sampling in dataset using bagging. After that I will use back propagation algorithm for training and testing. Suppose I will select randomly 40% data from the dataset to create 1 sample set. After that I will take again 40% data form the total dataset and create another dataset.

Code for sampling:

```
def subsample(dataset, ratio):
    sample = list()
    n_sample = round(len(dataset) * ratio)
    while len(sample) < n_sample:
        index = randrange(len(dataset))
        append(dataset[index])
        print(sample)
    return sample
```

Dataset:(I will do sampling on 20 datasets from UCI Machine Repository)

```
import pandas as pd
dataset =pd.read_csv("abalone.csv")
```

Comment: save each dataset to a dictionary (key= 'a number' and value=dataframe)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am totally new in this area. Can you help me to provide the code please. I have a code but I dont understand whether it is working or not.

Comment: This may be simpler than your current subsample function. [Example of generating random samples from Panda dataset](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-sample/)

Comment: you want to make 20 separate samples of `abalone` dataset, or sample 20 different datasets?

Comment: I have to use 20 datasets from UCI Machine Repository like abalone, thyroid, car, chess...etc. Now for each datasets I have to do sampling. Suppose think about abalone dataset. I need different sample of this dataset using bagging.

Comment: @DarrylG yes.Yes I want to do exacly this type of sampling. My supervisor said I have to do it using bagging algorithm. Dont understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make 20 samples of a dataset , u can use `pandas.DataFrame.sample` and store each of the samples to dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset =pd.read_csv("abalone.csv")
df_dict ={}
for i in range(20):
    df_dict['df{}'.format(i)] = dataset.sample(frac=0.4, random_state=123)
    # use 'replace = True' for Sample with replacement.
```

Comment: Thought poster wanted 20 samples from different datasets rather than 20 from one?  Namely: "I have to use 20 datasets from UCI Machine Repository like abalone, thyroid, car, chess...etc".  This seems like the right approach, except shouldn't the samples come from multiple CSV files?

Comment: @DarrylG, same can be applied to different datasets , and each of those dictionary can be saved, or can create a new dictionary with `key` as name of dataset and `value` as the current dict

Comment: @shijith--agreed, that's why I thought this was the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am talking with my supervisor about that. If I need anything more than that I will be back here. Thanks again.